# Having issues getting uploaded images to display on output page PHP

Tags: php

I cannot get an uploaded image to display on the output page with the other text-based information. I am very new to working with PHP and I am working on a practice project that enables a user to upload blog posts about products.

There is a form where the user submits information and an uploaded image. That information gets posted to another page with the blog posts. My issue is getting the image to show on the page with the rest of the output.

I'm probably making simple, really stupid mistakes. But after looking at this for so long, I'm unable to figure it out myself. I've tried googling everything I can think of in "upload and display images php" realm, and nothing has helped.

If anyone could help point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

There is one page for the upload form, newpost.php

here is the PHP for that:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$msg = "";
include('../includes/db_connect.php');
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $target ="images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $category = $_POST['category'];
    $uploads_dir = 'image/';
    $image = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $title = $db->real_escape_string($title);
    $price = $db->real_escape_string($price);
    $description = $db->real_escape_string($description);
    $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $description = htmlentities($description);

    if($title && $price && $description && $category && $image){
        $query = $db->query("INSERT INTO post (user_id, title, price, description, category_id, image) VALUES('$user_id', '$title', '$price', '$description', '$category', '$image')");
        if($query){
            echo "product posted";
        }else{
            echo "error";
        }
    }else{
        echo "missing data";
    }

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)){
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
    }else{
        $msg = "There was an error uploading the file";
    }
}

?>
```

and here is the HTML form:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>TITLE *</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Product title here" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>PRICE *</label>
            <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" 
            placeholder="Enter with the following format: 0.00 " required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>CATEGORY</label>
            <select name="category" class="form-control">
               <?php
                   $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories");
                   while($row = $query->fetch_object()){
                       echo "<option value='".$row->category_id."'>".$row->category."</option>";
                       }
               ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>PRODUCT DESCRIPTION *</label>
            <textarea type="textarea" name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Write a description of the product here" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>IMAGE(S) *</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
            <input type="file" name="image">
        </div>
        <div class="required">
            * indicates a required field
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">POST PRODUCT</button>
</form>
```

Now here is the PHP for the page where the posts display:

```
<?php
include('includes/db_connect.php');

$query = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, price, description, image FROM post");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($post_id, $title, $price, $description, $image);

?>
```

And here is my HTML so far. THIS IS WHERE MY ISSUE IS.

```
<?php
    while ($query->fetch()):
?>
<article>

    <h2><?php echo $title?></h2>
    <p>$<?php echo $price?></p>
    <p><?php echo $description?></p>
    <!-- I'm trying to get my image to show here and am having issues with that. The above information is visible and working as it should. The images just show up as broken image icons /-->
    <p><?php echo "<img src='images/".$image."' >";?></p>

 </article>

 <?php endwhile?>
```

Here is my sql table I am working from for the post:

```
CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` text NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `posted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `image` varchar(300) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thank you to anyone who looks at this an offers advice. I really appreciate it.

Comment: you need to narrow down the issue

Comment: Please go read [ask]. At least you need to describes to us what the actual _problem_ is. Just stating that you are "at a loss" does not cut it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't it be:
        `<p><?php echo "<img src='post/".$image."' >";?></p>`

1. Have you looked that the image exists in the 'images' directory?
2. Have you looked in the database, that the image is correct there?
   You can use phpmyadmin for this.